# How can I improve the speed of my table filtering JavaScript on smartphones?

Tags: javascript, performance, search

I want to filter a table with an input box. It works but it is slow on smartphones which are my target platform - Iphone, Htc Touch HD (800 rows take about 4sec to filter).

Please let me know if you can help speed this up.

```
function time(){
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();

    return time
}

function filter (phrase, _id){
    var starttime = time();
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementById(_id);
    var ele = null;
    var rows = new Array();
    for (var r=0 ; r < table.rows.length; r++){
        ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i=0 ; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i])!=-1){
                displayStyle = '';
            }else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        rows[r] = displayStyle;
    }
    alert((time() - starttime)/1000 +" Sec");
    for(var k=0; k < rows.length; k++){
        table.rows[k].style.display = rows[k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the performance is somewhat reasonable, given the platform, but here are a few ideas:

1.) Don't calculate the length of your arrays during each for iteration (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Arrays )

2.) perform your toLowerCase() on the search string once at the beginning, not during each row checked

3.) the biggest hog is *probably* your use of innerHTML and replace(), but it's going to depend on the browser implementation, see if you can replace it with a more efficient method of getting the text from the cells you need to compare.

Comment: +1 for the link (although you should make it a link), some good tips in it.

Answer (score 0):

Profile your JavaScript, using the [Firebug profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) for instance. Then you can see which operations take the longest. Measuring is knowing.